# How can I inject SQL and fetch data from a table

Tags: python

I'm trying to enter the database and fetch all the data from the table for learning purpose
I'm trying like

```
 or 1 = 1--or 1 = 1 #'or 1 = 1 /* , ') or '1' = '1-- , ') or (' 1 ' = ' 1--
```

But it does'nt works!

Here is my python code

```
    db = "./org.db"
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    print("Display user information\n")
    Name = "Ahmed"

    print(f"SELECT * from EMPLOYEE WHERE  FIRST_NAME={Name} ")
    c.execute(f"SELECT * from EMPLOYEE WHERE FIRST_NAME=:Name",{"Name":Name})

    result = c.fetchmany(size=2)
    print(result)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: According to the code, `Name` is just "Ahmed".  It does not contain all the extra things you listed at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using correct named placeholder in SQL statement in `c.execute`, which is an effective way to prevent SQL injection attack.

Try a python formatted string to see how SQL injection attack works.

```
Name = "'Ahmed' or 1 = 1"

c.execute(f"select * from EMPLOY where FIRST_NAME={Name}")
```

Comment: `Name = "'Ahmed' or 1 = 1"` would work, since `Ahmed` is a string.